# How to remove or disable the slash at the end of the URL?

Tags: url, web, slash

I don't know exactly what is the problem, but I have done a lot of research about trailing slash in PHP.

My problem is that when I visit my site I always see trailing slash and it causes all the resources to fail to load.

How do I disable trailing slash that's being added in `.htaccess`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not add / to URLs by default, it's your script doing that.

If you want to use the style.css regardless, use the *absolute* or the *full* path - so if your style.css is on `http://domain.com/style.css`, then you can either use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/style.css">
```

With your file.php thing, it looks in `http://domain.com/file.php/style.css`, while either of the above uses the file you created at `http://domain.com/style.css`.

That would as well work for `http://domain.com/folder/file.php` - simply use `/folder/style.css` in the `href`-tag or, once again, the full URL to it.

Comment: Thanks your answer solve the problem on the css stop working

but it doesn't solve the other problem when there is end of the slash the new page won't open

for example

http://mydomain.com/file.php/ when I want to open another link in the same page it will be http://mydomain.com/file.php/newpage.php instead it should be http://mydomain.com/newpage.php

Comment: You can do the very same with links if wanted, simply use `<a href="/newpage.php">...</a>` for links, the same principle for images and so on. However, keep in mind that it's a script issue that can only only be looked over now without access to those. I'm sure you've seen a few other php websites, relatively few use any trailing slashes (and if refering to WordPress and others, only for links easier to remember `domain.com/index.php?/2011/06/01/why-one-plus-one-is-five` -- However, your script shouldn't even append slashes to begin with.

Comment: I just notice that the slash been adding only when there a click on the images but not on the link text/ anyway thanks once again and I will just disable the image click and let them click on the text only and that should solve all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

The / in a URL indicates a directory on the file systen of your webserver so your request for `file.php/` is looking for a directory and not a PHP script file.

A htaccess rewrite so that any directory automatically has a trailing slash appended can be found in the rewrite guide:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here is what I found:

[Remove the trailing slash in url with htacess](http://blog.valtersboze.com/2009/06/add-or-remove-trailing-slash-in-url-with-htaccess/)
I think this is what you are looking for.

> How to find it:

Just do a search for [remove ending slash of url](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=remove%20ending%20slash%20of%20url)

Answer (score 0):

just use the full path to the css file for eg.
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yourdomain/folder/file.css"/>`